# Change home text and URL in Yii2 Breadcrumbs widget

Tags: php, yii2

I want to change default text "Home" and also the URL for home.
While searching on it I found suggestion that need to set [homeUrl](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBreadcrumbs) but I don't have any idea where to set it.
Please ask for code if you need it.

Comment: Obviously having the code would be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to configure [`$homeLink`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-breadcrumbs#$homeLink-detail) property:

```
echo Breadcrumbs::widget([
    'homeLink' => [
        'label' => 'My name',
        'url' => '/my/url',
    ],
    'links' => [
        // your items
    ],
    // rest of widget config
]);
```

Comment: i have replace `Breadcrumbs::widget([
            'links' => isset($this->params['breadcrumbs']) ? $this->params['breadcrumbs'] : [],
        ])` this code with `echo Breadcrumbs::widget([
   'homeLink' => [
    'label' => 'My name',
    'url' => Url::to(['venues-plan-packages/index']),
   ]
   // ...
  ]);` but now it is not showing any breadcrumb , I am doing anything wrong ?

Comment: @ParitoshMahale you should update the question and add info there, the code isnt readable in the comments section.

Comment: See my update - you should not remove `links` config, you should only add `homeLink` setting.